# Display RSS source in Firefox

Tags: firefox, rss

For some reasons, Firefox doesn't display rss feed source, it downloads it by default.
A trick is to manually add "view-source:" before the feed url but it's...manual.
Is there any workaround/extension to display rss feed source instead of download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's pretty easy. Just go to Settings/General/Applications and then change XML from "Save File" to "Open in Firefox"...